# Multiple Forms for New items in the same list

Tags: 2013, javascript

I am writing a book room application with Sharepoint 2013 foundation.

To avoid creating a Calendar List for each room, I would have a dropdown list in that have values: Room1, Room2, etc.

When using "+Add" in the webpart I need to set the default value for the dropdown list to Room1 or Room2.

**Solution 1**
Add second Calendar List with with Room1 and Room2 selected in newforms.aspx. How would I set the form id in the WebPart?

**Solution 2**
In NewForm.aspx the How would I get the Caller ID from the WebPart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you are looking to do is have multiple **content types** in the same list. You can create new content types under `Site Settings>Site Content Types`

In your case I would suggest selecting `List Content Types>Event` as your Parent content type.

Make two separate content types as required, then navigate to your calendar list settings to add additional content types to your list as described by this link:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-support-for-multiple-content-types-in-a-list-or-library-83e8efaa-902f-4d0c-9986-7e343ab7c12b

Comment: J.Doe Thanks, but how i set the Content Type A to View 1 and Content Type B to View 2?

Comment: If this is your selected approach I would recommend starting a new question on how to implement it, however with regards to your question the forms for new items are dependent on content type and will change dynamically according to your selection. To view the list in accordance with content type create a new page for each content type, add the list as a web part and create a custom view filtered on content type.

Comment: Thanks Doe. The View filter by content type is cool, but the sharepoint should detect and apply the correct contentype new item form... :(

Comment: Ensure that you have a difference in columns for each content type (even a Room1 or Room2 column that default to yes) to prevent issues when creating a custom form in spdesigner https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2c09d0b9-47df-414f-b2be-d80afe7b23c8/creating-new-item-form-uses-all-the-content-types?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: Another approach is to insert a custom newitem form into a custom page https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-list-form-2a231a5a-a650-43c4-8e2b-403474370307?CorrelationId=0c3f1cfc-1074-4a36-a1f0-92e77b7fd2eb&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010119111